# Showing that functional with continuous partial derivatives is a quadratic form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

From Serge Lang's Linear Algebra:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which has
>   partial derivatives of order $1$ and $2$, and such that the partial
>   derivatives are continuous functions. Assume that: $$f(tX)=t^2f(X)$$
>   for all $X \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Then $f$ is a quadratic form, that is
>   there exists a symmetric matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ such that $f(X) =
>  \sum_{i=0, j=0}^{n}{x_{ij}a_{ij}{x_{ij}}}$.
>
> The proof of course takes calculus of several variables. See for
>   instance my own book on the subject.

I don't have rigorous experience with real analysis on multiple variables, but I'm quite curious for why does this functional have quadratic form.

**(1)** First thing I noticed, is that if $t \in \mathbb{R}$, it is obvious by axiomatic definition that functional $f(X)$ is not linear (but I'm not sure how much significance this has).

**(2)** Second (perhaps slightly more relevant) thing I've noticed, is that if $f(X)$ has partial derivatives of order $1$ which are continous for all $X \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then from $f$ we can derive $1 \times n$ Jacobian matrix $J$:

$$J(f)=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x_1} & ...  & \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial x_n} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

But in this case, Jacobian matrix is not symmetric, therefore it can not be associated with quadratic form.

**(3)** If Jacobian matrix $J$ exists for $f$, and $f$ has continuous partial derivatives of order $2$, then there also exists Hessian $H$, because: $H(f(X))=J(\nabla f(X))^T$. But Hessian matrix, unlike Jacobian, is **always symmetric**. Therefore we have a symmetric $H$ such that:

$$H_{i, j} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}$$

which could be associated with quadratic form.

**(4)** Extra: I'm not sure how relevant this is, but I've also considered Clairaut's theorem which can be applied at some neighborhood in this case due to all second order partial derivatives being continuos. (But this is probably negligible here).

---

Is my "analysis" sufficient to show that $f$ is a quadratic form with symmetric matrix associated with it? Is there a possibility that matrix associated with $f$ is actually Hessian? If so, why precisely?

Comment: Your analysis is certainly not sufficient, because you haven't made use of the fact that $f(tX) = t^2 f(X)$. But yes, your intuition is right, the matrix associated with $f$ is infact the hessian of $f$ evaluated at the origin. To prove this, see my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297349/how-to-show-that-the-remainder-of-this-taylor-expansion-of-this-homogeneous-func/3298694#3298694

Comment: However, my answer there assumes that $f$ is $C^3$, not just $C^2$, so I'll have to see whether the same argument holds with this weaker hypothesis (in particular you should check the actual amount of regularity required in applying Taylor's theorem)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for the reference, never thought this would be related to Taylor's theorem. I'm also interested if your solution is completely compatible with this question, in particular there is an assumption that $f(O)=0$ and $f$ is a function of two variables (although I'm not sure if that affects anything).

Comment: take a look at the generalisation I wrote at the end of my answer. So, as long as you assume $f$ is $C^3$, then everything else which I wrote there holds word-for-word for the case you're interested in, namely when $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ satisfies $f(tX) = t^2 f(X)$. (notice that by choosing $t=0$, this already implies $f(0) = 0$). (By the way I was sloppy in my first comment; the matrix of $f$ should be twice the hessian at the origin, because there's already a $1/2$ coming from Taylor's theorem)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for the generalization! I guess all I have to do is to set $k=2$ which will satisfy the proof (but obviously information before that is very important as well, on how it is derived using taylor expansion).

Comment: yes that's right, and in fact, I just figured out that there is no need to assume $f$ is $C^3$; we can actually assume far less. I can write up an answer if you wish

Comment: @peek-a-boo Sure, it would be great if there is such compact proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments I was worried about the amount of regularity assumptions on $f$ needed for the statement to be true, but I now realised that we actually do not need much. In the spirit of the generalization I offered in my other answer, we can now state the following:

> Let $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ be given and let $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ be a given function such that for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$, $f(tx) = t^kf(x)$. If we assume in addition that $f$ is $k$-times [Frechet-differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)  at the origin, $0$ then
>   \begin{align}
> f(x) = \dfrac{1}{k!}d^kf_0(x^k)
> \end{align}
>   where I use $x^k$ as shorthand notation for the element $(x, \dots x) \in \underbrace{\Bbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times \Bbb{R}^n}_{k \text{ times}}$

Now, the case you're interested in is $k=2$, and in this case, $f$ being twice-Frechet differentiable at the origin is the same as saying the Hessian of $f$ (the deriavtive of the gradient) exists at the origin.

The proof is very similar to what I showed in the other answer. Define $g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by  $g(t) = f(tx) = t^kf(x)$. Notice that $g$ is a degree $k$ polynomial in terms of the variable $t$; hence it equals its own $k$-th order Taylor polynomial:
\begin{align}
g(t) = g(0) + g'(0) t + \dfrac{g''(0)}{2!} \cdot t^2 + \dots + \dfrac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} t^k
\end{align}
But notice that $g(0) = g'(0) = g''(0) = \dots g^{(k-1)}(0) = 0$ (because the first $k-1$ derivatives of $t^k$ at the origin all vanish). Hence, we have that
\begin{align}
g(t) = \dfrac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!} t^k.
\end{align}
Now, choosing $t=1$ implies that
\begin{align}
f(x) = g(1) = \dfrac{1}{k!}g^{(k)}(0)
\end{align}
Now, recall that by definition, $g(t) = f(tx)$; so if we now use the multivariable chain rule $k$ times on $g$, then we find that $g^{(k)}(0) = d^kf_0(x^k)$. Hence,
\begin{align}
f(x) = \dfrac{1}{k!}d^kf_0(x^k).
\end{align}

---

In the particular case $k=2$, this of course says that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} d^2f_0(x,x)$; or if you write it in terms of the Hessian matrix of $f$, and matrix multiplication, then
\begin{align}
f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} x^T \cdot H_f(0) \cdot x
\end{align}
($x^T$ means transpose, and $H_f(0)$ is the hessian matrix of $f$ evaluated at the origin)

---

**A word about hypotheses:**

By the way, the highlighted statement I made assumes less than the statement gievn in Lang's book. In other words, if $f$ has continuous partial derivatives up to order $2$ (which is what you assumed), then the second Frechet-derivative of $f$ at the origin, $d^2f_0$, exists and hence the theorem I stated can be applied.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! By the way, you only made the assumption that partial derivatives must exist and should be continuous at the origin only (or equivalently in finite-dimensional cases $f$ should be Frechet differentiable at $0$), correct? Whereas Lang has made assumption that partial derivatives of $f$ must be continuous for all $X$.

Comment: @ShellRox I only made the assumption that $f$ should be $k$ times Frechet Differentiable at the origin (which is actually a weaker assumption than continuity of $k$-th order partial derivatives at the origin). The proof I provided generalizes word-for word if we replace the domain $\Bbb{R}^n$ to an arbitrary (even infinite-dimensional) real Banach space $V$; the only thing is in infinite dimensions, you can't talk about hessian matrices... but, the Frechet derivatives still make perfect sense. I guess Lang made that assumption only to streamline the statement of the theorem

Comment: ... after all, it is a linear algebra book, not a book on multivariable calculus

Comment: My confusion came from [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Finite_dimensions), where they mention that "If all partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous, then $f$ is Fréchet differentiable". I guess Lang did not specify properties and structures of topological space $\mathbb{R^n}$ considering that this book is not for real analysis. But now I understand it, thank you!