# Example of function that is Gâteaux-differentiable but not Fréchet-differentiable

Tags: derivatives, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

I am looking for an example of a function that is Gateaux-differentiable but not Fréchet-differentiable. I know that there is a lot of example of function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ that satisfies this property. An example is
$$f(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3}{x^2 + y^2} & \text{if } (x, y) \neq 0,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
But since the Fréchet and Gâteaux derivative are defined for Banach spaces in general, I am looking for a more fancy example such as a function from $L^p$ to $L^q$ for instance. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way of constructing Gateaux, but not Frechet differentiable functions is to consider functions which are homogeneous of degree 1, but not (bounded and) linear. See the argument in [section 3.7, page 148 of Loomis and Sternberg](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eshlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf), or [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3298792/568204)
for a slight generalization. Note that this is precisely the reason why the $f$ you suggested has all directional derivatives, yet is not Frechet differentiable at the origin. Other examples like $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2yz^2}{x^4+y^4+z^4}$ if $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$ and $0$ otherwise will also have all directional derivatives, yet not be Frechet differentiable.

As a concrete example in infinite dimensions, fix a finite measure space $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$, and for $p\in [1,\infty]$, let $L^p$ denote $L^p(\mu,\Bbb{R})$, so we only consider real-valued functions. Consider the function $T:L^2\times L^2\times L^{\infty}\to L^1$ defined as
\begin{align}
T(f,g,h):=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{fgh}{\displaystyle\int_X(f^2+g^2+h^2)\,d\mu}&\text{if $(f,g,h)\neq 0$}\\\\
0 & \text{if $(f,g,h)=0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Note that by Holder's (or in this case Cauchy-Schwarz) inequality, $fgh$ does indeed lies in $L^1$ and because $f,g\in L^2$ and $h\in L^{\infty}$ with $\mu$ being a finite measure, the denominator will be finite if $(f,g,h)\neq (0,0,0)$; furthermore because we're only dealing with real-valued functions, the denominator only vanishes when $(f,g,h)=0$, so everything is well-defined.

Now, $T$ is easily verified to be homogeneous of degree $1$, but is not a bounded linear transformation. Hence, all the directional derivatives exist, but $T$ is not Frechet-differentiable.