# First variation $\delta J$ with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_{1,\infty}$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Assume that the Lagrangian $L$ is $C^2$, $y(x)$ is a $C^1$ curve and $\eta$ is a $C^1$ perturbation. Define
$$
J (y) = \int^b_a L(x,y,y')dx.
$$
If we define the first variation to be
$$
\left.\delta J\right|_{y}(\eta)=\int_{a}^{b}\left(L_{y}\left(x, y(x), y^{\prime}(x)\right) \eta(x)+L_{z}\left(x, y(x), y^{\prime}(x)\right) \eta^{\prime}(x)\right) d x,
$$
then it satisfies the relation
$$
J(y+\alpha \eta)=J(y)+\left.\delta J\right|_{y}(\eta) \alpha+o(\alpha)
\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
w.r.t variable $\alpha\in \Bbb{R}$, where $o(\alpha) = \alpha \psi(\alpha)$ such that if $\alpha \to 0$ then $\psi(\alpha) \to 0$ in at a faster pace, which is obvious by definition.

**The question is**: even if the $o$-relation w.r.t. $\alpha$ \eqref{1} above holds, the following analogous $o$-retlation w.r.t. a norm of the $\eta$ variable
$$
J(y+ \eta)=J(y)+\left.\delta J\right|_{y}(\eta) +o(\|\eta\|_{1,\infty}),
\label{2}\tag{2}$$
where $\|\eta\|_{1,\infty} = \|\eta\|_\infty + \|\eta'\|_\infty$,
does not hold in general. I have no idea how to show this fact.

**My attempt**. First, by using Taylor expansion with remainder, I wrote:
$$
L(x,y+\eta ,y'+\eta') = L(x,y,y')+ \bar{L}_y\eta + \bar{L}_z\eta'
$$
with $\bar{L}_y(x,y,\eta),\bar{L}_z(x,y,\eta') \to L_y(x,y,y'), L_z(x,y,y')$ when $\|\eta\|_\infty,\|\eta'\|_\infty \to 0$ respectively.
Then, seeking to obtain \eqref{2}, I substituted the found relation into into original formula, and got the following relation
$$
\begin{split}
|J(y+\eta)-J(y) -\delta J | & =\left| \int\big[(\bar{L}_y-L_y)(x,y,y')\big]\eta(x) + \big[(\bar{L}_z - L_z)(x,y,y')\big]\eta(x)'dx\right|\\
& \le \|\eta\|_{1,\infty}\int|(\bar{L}_y-L_y)(x,y,y')|+|(\bar{L}_z - L_z)(x,y,y')| dx
\end{split}
$$
Now I am stuck in showing that the last right hand term goes to zero when $\|\eta\|_{1,\infty} \to 0$.

Comment: This is essentially a restatement (to an infinite-dimensional space) of the fact that it is possible for all directional derivatives to exist even though a function may not be differentiable. Think back to the typical examples in the plane where you have a function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ which has all directional derivatives but not differentiable at the origin (think about the actual reason for why such a mapping is not differentiable, and try to adapt the answer here).

Comment: Is there $\|\dot\|_{1,\infty}$ norm analoge in finite dimension case?

Comment: The question of whether there's an analogue to $\|\cdot\|_{1,\infty}$ in finite-dimensional case is irrelevant. You're getting hung up on technicalities, and missing the "big picture" idea of why sometimes it is possible to have directional derivatives yet not be differentiable. Try to come up with a homogeneous but non-linear function, because such a function has directional derivatives, but not differentiable. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4123772/568204) for more details. See if you can adapt the reasoning to come up with an example for your question.

Comment: @Daniele Tampieri , Hello I found this question on page 36 of Daniel Liberzon's Optimal control book,which says it holds for $\|\cdot\|_{1,\infty}$ norm but not uniform norm?You made a wrong edition?

Comment: @yili mmmh, I am not sure, since functionals which are Gâteaux but not Frechet differentiable exist in every Banach space. Maybe the fact that the Lagrangian is $C^2$ plays a role in this fact: anyway, I'll correct my edit as soon as possible. If you want to taste a flavor of the big picture pertaining functional deryvatives, you may want to have a look at [this Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives/349584#349584).

Comment: $C^2$ condition is not assumed in Daniel Liberzon's book,I post it to make the question a bit easier if it is possible.

Comment: @Daniele Tampieri I'm not sure whether the result,can be used to prove the result here? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4296721/360262